# When creating subdocument, it only shows id - not the created subdoc data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey this is my first stackoverflow question and I'm also new to coding(3-4 months) so bear with me.

#### What's the problem you're trying to solve?

I want to create a subdoc(issues) of my main resource(project).  Upon creating, it only pushes and shows the generated id, and not the data I submitted on creation.

#### Post any code you think might be relevant (one fenced block per file)

project.js(main resource)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const issueSchema = require('./issue')

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  targetStartDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  targetEndDate: {
    type: Date
  },
  issues: [ { issueSchema } ],
  owner: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  createdDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema)
```

issue.js(subdoc of main resource)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const issueSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  summary: {
    type: String
  },
  identifiedBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String
  },
  identifiedDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  targetResolutionDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  resolutionSummary: {
    type: String
  },
  lastModifiedDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

module.exports = issueSchema
```

issue_routes.js

```js
router.post('/projects/:id/issues', requireToken, (req, res, next) => {
  const issueData = req.body.issue
  issueData.username = req.user.username
  console.log(issueData)
  Project.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(handle404)
    .then(project => {
      project.issues.push({ issueData })
      return project.save()
    })
    .then(project => res.status(201).json({ project }))
    .catch(next)
})
```

create.sh(issue create)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl "http://localhost:4741/projects/${ID}/issues" \
  --include \
  --request POST \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" \
  --data '{
    "issue": {
      "summary": "'"${SUM}"'",
      "identifiedDate": "'"${IDD}"'",
      "targetResolutionDate": "'"${TRD}"'",
      "resolutionSummary": "'"${RS}"'",
      "status": "'"${STAT}"'"
    }
  }'

echo
```

#### If you see an error message, post it here. If you don't, what unexpected behavior are you seeing?

```
~/PersonalProjects/Bug-Board-api (lightspeed-tortilla)
$ TOKEN=a084fd4dacfbb631c939f858909a4ae0 ID=6082c928d7caf889ffb35168 SUM="SUMMARYHERE" IDD=02/01/2222 TRD=02/02/2223 RS="NICESUMMARY" STAT="DONEZO" sh curl-scripts/issues/create.sh 
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:7165
Vary: Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 283
ETag: W/"11b-IWQFxUMdF3H5c26tClSVsKBxlfc"
Date: Fri, 23 Apr 2021 13:29:36 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

{"project":{"_id":"6082c928d7caf889ffb35168","name":"NOTESHERE","targetStartDate":"2222-02-02T06:00:00.000Z","targetEndDate":"2223-02-02T06:00:00.000Z","owner":"6082c8e4d7caf889ffb35167","issues":[{"_id":"6082cbc094a9918b5656ccef"}],"createdDate":"2021-04-23T13:18:32.799Z","__v":1}}
```

#### What is your best guess as to the source of the problem?

Maybe I'm not pushing the correct data?

Comment: "console.log(issueData)" - what does this output?

Comment: "Mongoose has two distinct notions of subdocuments: arrays of subdocuments and single nested subdocuments." Here, you schema defines a path pointing to an array of objects containing a subdocument property. Do you know this setup to actually be valid?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev heres an example of me trying to create a new issue with the issueData being console.log

{
  summary: 'WOW NEW SUMMARY',
  identifiedDate: '01/01/3333',
  targetResolutionDate: '01/02/3333',
  resolutionSummary: 'NEW SUMMARY',
  status: 'IN PROGRESS',
  username: 'NewUsernameI'
}

Comment: @IAmDranged I apologize for my confusion, but are you asking if [ { issueSchema } ] is a valid way?  This is the first time I've tried it like that, the last time I was able to make this work I only wrapped it in an array, and not an object inside of an array

Comment: Yes. Your issue schema doesn't seem to be accounted for, if only for the fact that you're not providing a value for the required identifiedBy path when saving your document - and still it somehow doesn't throw any error. This, combined with the quotation from the mongoose documentation that I provided in my earlier comment, lead me to believe that there may an issue with this particular setup.

Comment: That kind of looks like it might be saving it as a ref.  What happens if you `populate` the `issues` field?